# Pick a random picture from a directory

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my current code:

```
const superagent = require("snekfetch");
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const random = require('random')
const os = require('os')

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
     if (!message.channel.nsfw) {
        message.react('');
        return message.channel.send({embed: {
                color: 16734039,
                description: "CO TY ROBISZ! TE ZDJENCIA SA TYLKO DLA DOROSLYCH! (idz na kanal NSFW)"
            }})
    }
    superagent.get('https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/ero')
        .end((err, response) => {
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(":smirk: Eevee")
      .setImage(random.choice(os.listdir("./app/eevee")))
      .setColor(`RANDOM`)
      .setFooter(`Tags: eevee`)
      .setURL(response.body.url);
  message.channel.send(embed);
    }).catch((err) => message.channel.send({embed: {
                color: 16734039,
                description: "Something is wrong... :cry:"
            }}));
    
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "eevee",
    description: "Fajno zdjencia",
    usage: "eevee",
    type: "NSFW" 
}
```

When I try to run it, I get this error message:

> TypeError: os.listdir is not a function

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: The error? and you are using `RichEmbed()` which is v11. You need to use `MessageEmbed()`

Comment: What's the error message? Add it to your question please :)

Comment: @Toasty i added the error to the question.

Comment: It seems to be only allowed in an NSFW channel. Is the channel you're playing this an NSFW channel?

Comment: @PerplexingParadox Yes I am executing the command in an NSFW channel, if I try to execute it in a non-nsfw channel I do not get any errors, and it correctly sends what it has to send (which is an error saying to execute it in an nsfw channel)

Comment: Could you `console.log(err);` then? That way we can see the real reason.

Comment: @eclipsek20 I actually meant the error that is issued by the program. In your `.catch((err) => [...])` block, add `console.log(err)` and add the result / error you recive to the question

Comment: @Toasty This is what i get `2021-04-19T11:52:34.324514+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: os.listdir is not a function
2021-04-19T11:52:34.324521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/commands/eevee.js:18:34
2021-04-19T11:52:34.324523+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:211:22
2021-04-19T11:52:34.324524+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)`

Comment: @PerplexingParadox This is what i get `2021-04-19T11:52:34.324514+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: os.listdir is not a function 2021-04-19T11:52:34.324521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/commands/eevee.js:18:34 2021-04-19T11:52:34.324523+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:211:22 2021-04-19T11:52:34.324524+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the `os` package but after a bit of researching I've found no `readdir` function. If you want to get all files of a `directory` you also can do it like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const allMyFiles = fs.readdirSync();
```

Also you are creating your `embed` with `RichEmbed()` which is **outdated**. Since **[v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)** you have to use **[MessageEmbed()](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#richembed-constructor)**:

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Test')
   [...]
```